# WiFi drivers error with Adaptor(Intel Corporation Wireless 3165) on Debian 11

Tags: debian, kernel, wifi, driver

I installed `Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) x86_64`(Xfce) But its `WiFi` isn't working. I even changed my kernel from `5.10`(default) to `5.18.0-2-amd64`.

When I Checked:

```
randomguy@randomguy-vostro153568:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[   16.318634] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   16.320292] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode (-2)
[   16.320298] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode failed with error -2
[   16.320311] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-28.ucode (-2)
[   16.320314] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-28.ucode failed with error -2
[   16.320324] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode (-2)
[   16.320326] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode failed with error -2
[   16.320336] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode (-2)
[   16.320338] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
[   16.320347] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode (-2)
[   16.320348] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
[   16.320357] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode (-2)
[   16.320359] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
[   16.320369] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode (-2)
[   16.320370] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
[   16.320380] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode (-2)
[   16.320381] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode failed with error -2
[   16.320383] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-7265D-22
[   16.320386] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-7265D-29
[   16.320388] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

`Ip link` not showing Wlan0(wlp1s0) Interface:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:2b:59:53:ff:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 36:f8:28:74:b1:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

My WiFi Adaptor:

```
randomguy@randomguy-vostro153568:~$ lspci -nn | grep Wireless
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
```

I Have never(ever) Played with kernel and Drivers before (because everything just worked out-of-the-box in every linux). So i don't know what to do at this point.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
After Searching 20 Pages of google!
My Problem was solved by Installing `iwlwifi`.

Connect your Host with Internet Anyhow(I did with USB tethering) and run following commands.

```
apt update && apt install firmware-iwlwifi
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

[Source](https://%20https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi)